# What brand of roasting dish would you recommend?

Tags: cookware, roast

Over the last few years I've gone through at least 3 roasting trays that have some kind of coating that has worn off - mostly ones bought in supermarkets.

I'd like to get something that will last, having discovered that decent cast-iron pans and casseroles are worth the investment.

What will it be used for? Mostly chicken - sometimes dry, sometimes in stock and wine - but reasonably often for duck and beef, so preferably something that has a rack.

I'm based in the UK, so preferably not a US-only brand - although many US brands are imported.

(More importantly - any seriously bad experiences with stuff not living up to it's reputation?)

Comment: If the coating is the issue, have you considered a non-coated pan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the castiron stuff from Le Creuset; my father-in-law has one that's at least 50 years old and it's still going strong. Lifetime warranty, too.

http://www.lecreuset.co.uk/Product-Range-uk/Cast-Iron-Cookware/Oven-Dishes/

They have roasting racks to fit as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to sound stupid and say that I didn't know they did roasting dishes (we've got several Crueset casseroles and pans and that's exactly the kind of investment I was thinking of). The roasters are just not v.obvious on Harts of Stur, but I've found them now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if these brands are available in the UK, but I have a review from Cook's Country a few years back that recommended the stainless roasting pans from Calphalon, Cuisinart, and KitchenAid.

Comment: Thanks - I can see stockists of all three brands, but it looks like the selection is restricted for Calphalon and KitchenAid (more of an appliance company over here).

Answer (score 1):

This weekend I discovered a [Römertopf](http://www.romertopfonline.com/) in my kitchen :) (I think it was a wedding present!)

I know almost nothing about it, apparently it could be a good alternative for roasting meat without it drying out.

Here's a photo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have a couple of high-quality ceramic roasting pans that we like. They're not like a true roaster with lid and all that, but a much nicer alternative to the standard thin metal 9" x 13" pan. They work just as well for cooking, clean more easily and can go directly to the table because they look nice.

The one downside, of course, is that they're breakable. They won't likely break in normal use, but I wouldn't want to drop them.

I think one is LeCreuset ceramic and one if Emile Henry.